# Is there a "my questions" or "my dashboard" view?

Tags: support, questions

I'm a new user on SO and am trying to find the 'right' way to use it. Right now I'm looking for the page to put into my bookmarks.

Is there something like a dashboard where I can have an overview of my questions and answers despite my profile page?

Comment: You might be interested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31486/question-dashboard-greasemonkey-script

Comment: What information are your looking for in an overview?

Comment: @EricJLN Basically what @Chacha102 told me with his answer, everything what 'Recent Activity' shows me. My questions and reactions to them on one page so I can open it with all the other forums and blogs I surf to every morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Recent Activity' page shows you stuff that has happened in your questions/answers recently.
(Click the envelope on the top bar)

The envelope will turn orange if something has happened, and it will stay that way until you click on it.

Your profile page shows you latest questions/answers.
(Click Your Name on the top bar)

Frankly, I just know what my reputation is at, and if it increases I'll check the recent activity page.

Comment: Oh yes, that's it. I didn't know I could click on the envelope and it isn't linked (or I didn't see it) after clicking on my username.

Okay, so reputation seems to be linked to answers, too? Have to search read the FAQ again, I think.

But back to 'Recent Activity', this is really good starting point to come back to SO if I only want to watch my own contributions and the reactions.

The only thing to wish for, is a "since your last visit" feature, but I think I can invest 2 brain cells to remember ;)

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to accept an answer.

Comment: Completely right.

I just discovered that the 'Recent Activity' page even is "since your last visit"-like.

Answer (score 1):

The closest to "bookmarks" is "favorites". Click on the star underneath the score for a question, and it toggles whether or not that question is a favorite. Then on your profile page, click on the "favorites" tab to see them all.

To see *your* questions, I'd just use the profile page.

Comment: I think he meant he wants a certain page to bookmark.

Comment: Exactly, but this answered another question I didn't even know yet I would have it. So thanks ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [search feature](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:me).

Comment: Yeah, that's quite a nice overview of the questions I contributed in. And quite easy to remember, too. Like it!